# Generate debug versions of targets in a DRY method

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, target

I am using GNUmake and I have a makefile with some targets defined and their respective dependencies. I would like to create a debug version of these targets, so I have this:

```
TARGET := a b c

all: $(TARGET)

a: a.o e.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $(^) -o $(@)

b: b.o g.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $(^) -o $(@) -pthread

c: f.o c.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -lm -c $(^) -o $(@)

%.o:    %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $(^) -o $(@)
```

So this is all good, but now I would like to create debug versions of these rules, but I don't want to have to rewrite the rules. I just want to add additional flags like `-g -DDEBUG` to the `CFLAGS` variable and change the names of the targets.

I tried this static rule stuff

```
$(TARGET:%=debug_%):    %: * #<--- not sure how to specify the dependencies
# CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG <-- uncommenting this line is an error
```

This didn't work. I wanted the above rule to match the targets I already specified, but add additional parameters to `CFLAGS` which will then generate files like `debug_a`, `debug_b`, `debug_c` etc. I am not sure if this is possible with make but that was just the way I was reasoning about this.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a suitable solution:

```
DEBUG_TARGET := $(TARGET:%=debug_%)

debug: $(DEBUG_TARGET)

$(DEBUG_TARGET):
debug_%: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug_%: %
    @mv $* debug_$*
```

This will generate a debug version of each target without having to create separate rules.

The last line was the sweet spot for me and this accomplishes what I wanted without having to repeat myself too much